# GIF manipulation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, animated-gif

Is it possible, **without** an external code library, to separate a .gif file into its individual frames, and conversely, to assemble a group of images into one?

I have spent a while playing with the System.Drawing namespace, and cannot seem to figure out how.

Also, I cannot figure out what to pass as a parameter for GetFrameCount. I do not know what they mean by a "dimension", and apparently it cannot be left null.

Additionally, is it possible to have playback control over the gif without first splitting it and recompiling/displaying in a way that mimics playback?

Thanks for the help.

This is in vb.net, 2008.

EDIT: If it is not possible without an external library, what is the best one to use?

Comment: I once found a C# free library + source that could do it. But by the time I converted it into VB.NET so I could merge it with my program I had busted something.... Sorry for a pretty useless answer, I'm pretty sure I found the original lib on CodeProject

Comment: Its okay lol. What was the lib on CodeProject?

Answer (score 4):

I used code similar to this and it worked just fine... I didn't invent it, so credit to the person who did (I've forgotten)... (maybe [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/fcb7d14d-d15b-4336-971c-94a80e34b85e)).

```
Private Class Frame
    Public Property MilliSecondDuration As Integer
    Public Property Bitmap As Image
    Public Sub New(ByVal duration As Integer, ByVal img As Bitmap)
        Me.MilliSecondDuration = duration
        Me.Bitmap = img
    End Sub
End Class

Private Function SeparateGif() As Frame()

    Dim gif As Image = Image.FromFile("MyGif.gif")

    Dim fd As New Imaging.FrameDimension(gif.FrameDimensionsList()(0))
    Dim frameCount As Integer = gif.GetFrameCount(fd)
    Dim frames(frameCount) As Frame

    If frameCount > 1 Then
        Dim times() As Byte = gif.GetPropertyItem(&H5100).Value
        For i As Integer = 0 To frameCount - 1
            gif.SelectActiveFrame(fd, i)
            Dim length As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(times, 4 * i) * 10
            frames(i) = New Frame(length, New Bitmap(gif))
        Next
    End If

    Return frames

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/fcb7d14d-d15b-4336-971c-94a80e34b85e) saving the animated GIF is not supported in .NET. So no, without an external code library, it's likely not possible.

Any particular reason you're averse to external libs?

Comment: This *would* have been for a commercial project, so I would like to avoid using external libraries as much as possible.

Comment: But i guess I could just make this open source, if it is impossible without a lib.

Comment: Many open source libraries these days allow for use in a commercial software product.

Comment: Okay...can you please find me one which would allow me to use it commercially for this purpose? Thanks for the help!